# Help storing byte array

Tags: arrays, bytes

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract Storage {

    uint8[5][5] public data;

    function Storage() public {

    }

    function setData(uint8[] _data) {
        for (int i=0;i<5; i++)
            data[i][1]=_data[i];
    }

    function getData() public constant returns(uint8[5][5]){
        return data;
    }


}
```

on my web3 page i call the contract to store the data:

```
        var byteArray = new Uint8Array(25);                
        var randomArray = [0x80, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05,
                          0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05,
                          0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05,
                          0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05,
                          0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05];    
storeSC.setData(byteArray , function (error, result) {
        if (!error)
            document.getElementById('response').innerHTML = 'Success:' + result
        else
            console.error(error);
    });
```

Anybody can explain me why passing `randomArray` everything works but I send out a lot more data than needed, passing  `byteArray` I get:

```
invalid number of arguments to solidity function
```

I just want to be able to pass a set of bytes to the method setData, any help on how to do it please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect this is a problem with using js typed array object, a single instance, which is not an array. Convert to number array first perhaps, using this https://stackoverflow.com/q/12760643/442396

Comment: Thank you this solved the problem, the array passed however wasn't really of 8bit, i guess i need to find a way around that

Comment: @Counterit ok pls upvote

Comment: Afaik int must be converted to a big integer .